# R: Why did the output for my COX ph yield an NA?

Tags: r, cox-regression

I am currently doing a COX regression model to investigate the interaction between a categorical variable and a numerical variable on R.

Using hypothetical terms, I shall use df$a(categorical variable) and df$b(numerical variable). The categorical variable itself has 5 different terms (think of the group as colours, and the terms inside were red, blue, green, gold and others).

In inserting the formula into the coxph code such that:

```r
coxfit2 <- coxph(formula = surv_object ~ df$a:df$b + confounder1, data = df)
summary(coxfit2)
```

Without going into details, i did input the respective confounding factors into the COXPH model as well. The code managed to run and gave reasonable values, but only when it comes to df$aOthers:df$b, the value output were NA and 0. Does anyone have any idea how to rectify this or is there any mistakes or improvements in this analysis?

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data?

Comment: Say I want to see if there is an interaction between 5 toxins (A, B, C, D and E). E the group others, which I created because the respective variables have a lower frequency. The other independent variable I would like to see if it interacts with is the volume of urine, which is a numerical value). Survival object is the event and the time to death. 
So the data would be something like

Toxin           AverageUrineVolume
A                    800
A                    1200
B                    200
.
I would like to find Toxin:Urine Volume, but it yielded NA for Others (E). @ErfanGhasemi

Comment: Your descriptions are helpful but if others have a part of your data, could reproduce the model. Can you post a representative sample with dput(x)? @Dreadfulcoding

Comment: @ErfanGhasemi, unfortunately, I am not very sure of how to use that function. I am afraid that I am unable to share a sample data as well due to confidentiality issues. Could I ask if you have any clue what the problem is with my coding above which yielded an NA output for df$aOthers:df$b in the coxph function? Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.